Parameter being passed as empty to the Twilio function
I'm developing a chatbot, each person's response adds points to a score, for me to add this score I used Twilio functions, however any second parameter that I pass within the function is coming up as empty.
I don't know what to do lol.
In flow data the variables are being assigned correctly, I really don't understand what is happening
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tVzXqFOqBU8jLWFfkZjD7pajkZEBPTL_?usp=sharing

Can you please add a screenshot of the flow as well as the snippet of your Function? It's probably also worth having a look in the Error Log debugging tool as this will provide more context

I added a link to the drive with some prints

One first sight, everything looks right. It's not clear if the first parameter makes it through either because you init it to 0 if it doesn't exist. I'd suggest to let the function fail immediately with return callback("error simulated", twiml); and then check the error log I mentioned above and search for a "82005 - Function execution resulted in an error log" entry. You can then click on it and see which parameters are actually sent

Also, please don't link a private gdrive and upload the images in the text box. It will render them as links but that's easy to fix
